# Is this from a Lego set?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Can anyone tell me which set this partial build is from?  Any help to identify it is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: [The 4 x 4 corner plate does not appear to come in purple in any official LEGO sets](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30503). Do the pieces say "LEGO" on the stud?

Comment: I don't have the lego with me. I saw it in a charity shop. In the past I've bought bags from charity and managed to work out what they are but i'm having difficulty with this one.

Comment: The yellow brick on top looks like a bootleg, are you sure that is a legit LEGO piece?

Comment: Can you take it apart? Lego Bricks always come in only one color (unless you consider the printing on some of them.

Comment: Whoops, never considered that you didn't have em with you. Sorry 

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely that this is not an official Lego set. There has been such a piece (the purple ones) but it never came in that color, therefore it must have been manufactured from a clone brand. There could be that 00.1% chance of it being a piece from an official Lego set, but based on the poor quality of the build in the image and the fact that Bricklink couldn't find it, I still think it's from a clone brand. Also, if any of the plates have only specific studs with holes in them that aren't in a reasonable pattern (such as outline of house walls), then there's a big chance that the plate came from Mega Blocks and not Lego™.

Comment: I did some zooming out. It is hard to tell due to the low resolution but I'm 99% certain that none of the visible nobs on the green pieces have the Lego logo. So it almost has to be a clone brand.

Comment: Indeed.  None of the studs have holes in them either, but still likely to be  a clone brand.