# How to eliminate a gap of an offset in a corner

Tags: building, design, ldd

So I need to build a layer with offset bricks, which I have managed to figure out. However, the corner is a problem. The dark bricks in my pic need to be in that position. How do I fill the gap between them around the corner? I'm assuming i will need to use a headlight brick but how? 
(I have managed to work out what to do in straight line, but now the corner is a problem. 
[image]

Update:

Thanks, that makes sense, it was the half spaces I was wondering about. A bad attempt at clarifying but here it goes. [image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are looking to achieve here. There seem to be few places falling under your description. Perhaps you could attach another picture showing the issue? It might be easier to suggest the exact solution.

Comment: Dear Katniss, So, that all of us here are on the same page with you, please upload a picture of your solution to the straight line sides of your wall, and maybe all together we can come up with a solution for that pesky corner.

Comment: What are you building on the offset row?

Comment: sorry everyone, I've not had time to devote to this lately, work has been crazy and I am not that familiar with the Digital designer yet, so it takes me a while to create something intelligible that I can then screenshot. I will be back latest by this afternoon with a new, more detailed image.

Comment: thanks everyone, managed to work out a way to fill the gap, but now can't work out how to add the next layer so the studs align back to 'normal'. I'm guessing the answer lies with more jumper plates but I just can't work out how.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

***UPDATE:*** Attempt Number Two.
[image]

Okay, everything's set up *almost* like your first uploaded image:

- Stone Gray 1x2 *jumper plates* as the base is the same.
- The three Black 1x1 *Bricks* are still in those key positions, except they're all modified *Headlight Bricks*, instead.
- All bricks have been skewered through with a combination of *Light
  Sword Blades* and *Shafts*.

  [image]
- *LEGO Digital Draw* won't allow placement of a brick on a stud-less surface.  To get around this I used 1x12 and 1x6 *plates* for temporary
  staging, and then deleted them after the *shish kebabbing*.

  [image]
- There's still a gap, but the gap number has been reduced to one, and
  made less noticeable.

  [image]
  [image]

Let me know if anyone wants the build file (Minus *[Picasso's Junk Lighthouse](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/9910/is-this-from-a-lego-set-large-white-sections-with-purple-plates)* behind it.).

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you are planning to do, there are several options. @Rin Rio-Oki showed solutions for when you are planning to build a fence-like structure, but if this is supposed to be a solid wall, here are three options:

[image]

The option furthest back is where you use a 1x1 brick with side stud and a tile in the corner. You could alternatively replace one of these with a headlight brick and a cheese slope if you want the corner to have an angle.

The middle option and the front option use a Technic 1x1 brick as a jumper (as it has a hollow stud on the top) to put the top plate in line with the bottom plate, which then allows you to line up your other bricks with the corner. Two different solutions for this are shown. I have color-coded the bricks for ease of reference (right side of the picture shows all the bricks used).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem a couple years ago and was able to solve it. The trick is to use the piece [6134](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6134#T=C), which is a quarter of a plate thick. It's an old question but I thought it would be good for a picture to be here in case others run into this problem and find this question.

[image: Simple showcase, old pic.]

Answer (score 1):

An idea occurred to me so I installed LDraw to make this image:

[image]

In the left figure I used a 2x2 offset tile to get the corner to meet.

On the right figure there is 1/2 stud offset in both directions that the 2x2 tile will fit into.

I cannot find a "legal" way to loose the offset at the top and bottom.